# IIS can't access hostname but localhost

Tags: iis

I don't know why do my IIS can't connect / bind the hostname. It works good if I browse with the localhost (http://localhost:23152), but it doesn't work if i browse with the hostname (http://test.company.com:23152). I already registered the hostname in hosts file (C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts)

It **works** good without hostname
[image]

It **doesn't work** with hostname
[image]

Here's when I try to ping the hostname (as you can see, the IP Address doesn't show the 127.0.0.1)
[image]

Is there something I'm missing?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks :)

Comment: is test.company.com definately the machine you're on? sometimes depending on routing it maybe trying to go out past a firewall and back in.....

Comment: i think test.company.com is just some random name i used. Any suggestion where should I start to trace the problem?

Comment: Well does test.company.com returns an IP, is that IP assigned to the server?

Comment: ya, please see at my picture above. I don't know where's the ip coming from, doesn't it supposed to show 127.0.0.1?

Comment: No that doesnt show the IP is on the server you're running IIS on that just means you can ping it... thats like saying you can find London on a map, doesnt mean you live there.

The actual server needs to know it is that 36.86.63.180 IP address, and that has to be a network its part of.. otherwise you're barking up the wrong tree.. and yes, all machines have 127.0.0.1 on :P

Comment: @Webster I am facing the same issure. Did you find the solution? I think you may not remember it... almost 3yr from question time.